# Can't get the connection to MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb

I would like to use my MariaDB database but I get the error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

My **pom.xml** includes:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also I have downloaded the file `mariadb-java-client-2.4.1-sources.jar` and placed it into WEB-INF/lib.

**Database.java**

```
package ch.yourclick.zt;

import java.sql.*;

    public class Database {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            // Ensure we have mariadb Driver in classpath
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");

            // create our mysql database connection
            String host = "localhost";
            String dbname = "zt_productions";
            String url = "jdbc:mariadb://" + host + "/" + dbname;
            String username = "root";
            String password = "test";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            // our SQL SELECT query.
            // if you only need a few columns, specify them by name instead of using "*"
            String query = "SELECT * FROM users";

            // create the java statement
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();

            st.close();
        }
    }
```

I also tried it with `Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`.

No matter what I try, I always get the same error message. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check if the jar is included in your maven project dependencies. Your code is correct. Also try to hit alt + f5 to update your project with the dependencies you added in the pom

Comment: @AndréCarvalho if I use `mvn dependency:tree`, I get `org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:jar:1.1.7:compile`. So I guess the jar file is included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong jar file. The source won't help you out.

Instead of `mariadb-java-client-2.4.1-sources.jar`, try using `mariadb-java-client-2.4.1.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this Problem myself:
the solution was quite simple... MariaDB is basically still MySQL. In the Url you are using to connect to the Database (jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306) you can therefore just use jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 <- i just replaced mariadb with mysql. It is still running on a mariadb server but it works so dont change it ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).